# Click to list item in CalendarView

Tags: android

I'm trying to click current day in my CalendarView like code below

```
((ListView) calendar.findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.err.println("click");

            }
        });
```

, but this way doesn't help me and I don't know why. How can I bind click listener to CalendarView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CalendarView` has a nested listener interface `CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener` with the method `onSelectedDayChange(...)`. You can implement it with custom logic and set using `Calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(...)` method.